# KDE global bindkey for 'accept-line'

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to bind Ctrl-j keys to send 'accept-line' in KDE?

`readline` library has a nice feature called key bindings. There are quite a few default keybindings user may want to use. To see it, one can use `bind -p` command. I found keybinding `C-j` (accept-line) useful. With it you can not to use Enter key to send Return. Instead you can use Ctrl-j. It is especially useful if you can press Ctrl fast (say, it is swapped with Alt key).

I also found a method to set up GTK apps. For example, to send message in Pidgin with `C-j` one can use this in `gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
binding "my-bindings"
{
    bind "Return" { "insert-at-cursor" ("\n") }
    bind "<ctrl>j" { "message_send" () }
}
widget "*pidgin_conv_entry" binding "my-bindings"
```

So with exception of KDE, all my apps can use accept-line. Is it possible to configure KDE so it'll interpret `C-j` as Enter? I need at least KRunner to understand this keys.